# Python: Correct way of using proxybroker lib with asyncio

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, proxy, python-asyncio

I want to use the [ProxyBroker](https://proxybroker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html) lib in my python program to generate a list/queue of 10 working proxies.

Unfortunately I was not able to find anything similar in the [example page](https://proxybroker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html) of the lib.

This is what I got right now, but it feels like I'm using asyncio the wrong way to complete my task. Especially the `gather` function I'm using in combination with the `collect(proxies)` call.

```py
    def get_proxies(self, limit=10):
        async def collect(proxies):
            p = []
            while True:
                proxy = await proxies.get()
                if proxy is None:
                    break
                p.append(proxy)
            return p

        proxies = asyncio.Queue()
        broker = Broker(proxies)
        tasks = asyncio.gather(
            broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
            collect(proxies))
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        proxy_list = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
        loop.close()
        return proxy_list
```

What would be the preferred/correct way of generating the proxy list?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this:

```
    """Find and show 10 working HTTP(S) proxies."""
    
    import asyncio
    from proxybroker import Broker
    
    async def show(proxies):
        while True:
            proxy = await proxies.get()
            if proxy is None: break
            print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)
    
    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    tasks = asyncio.gather(
        broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
        show(proxies))
    
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

or if you want to generate a file:

```
import asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker


async def save(proxies, filename):
    """Save proxies to a file."""
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        while True:
            proxy = await proxies.get()
            if proxy is None:
                break
            proto = 'https' if 'HTTPS' in proxy.types else 'http'
            row = '%s://%s:%d\n' % (proto, proxy.host, proxy.port)
            f.write(row)


def main():
    proxies = asyncio.Queue()
    broker = Broker(proxies)
    tasks = asyncio.gather(broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
                           save(proxies, filename='proxies.txt'))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is all!

Good look!