# convert async object into a list

Tags: python, asynchronous

I'm trying to get a list of proxies from proxybroker:

```
import asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker

async def show(proxies):
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None: break
        print('Found proxy: %s' % proxy)

proxies = asyncio.Queue()
broker = Broker(proxies)
tasks = asyncio.gather(
    broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10),
    show(proxies))

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result_now = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

However, I'm not sure how to convert the final result into a normal list. Any help? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is the [basic example](https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/blob/d21aae8575fc3a95493233ecfd2c7cf47b36b069/examples/basic.py) from [ProxyBroker's GitHub repository](https://github.com/constverum/ProxyBroker/tree/d21aae8575fc3a95493233ecfd2c7cf47b36b069).  I looked at the Broker function's source code to see if there was some parameter that could be enabled.  The only parameter was writing the proxy query results to a file, which isn't what you requested.

I noted that when I requested `type(proxy)` it returned `<class 'proxybroker.proxy.Proxy'>` object.  These objects can be appended to a list in your `show(proxies)` function, which you can return after `loop.run_until_complete(tasks).`

There are others ways to accomplish your use case, but the one below is quick and accomplishes your requirement with minimal code changes.

```
import asyncio
from proxybroker import Broker

proxy_data = []

async def show(proxies):
    global proxy_data
    while True:
        proxy = await proxies.get()
        if proxy is None:
            break
        # the `str` allows you to manipulate the list items
        proxy_data.append(str(proxy))


proxies = asyncio.Queue()
broker = Broker(proxies)
tasks = asyncio.gather(
    broker.find(types=['HTTP', 'HTTPS'], limit=10), show(proxies)
)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)


for item in proxy_data:
    print(item)
    # output 
    <Proxy US 0.12s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 208.80.28.208:8080>
    <Proxy US 0.12s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 3.96.119.90:8081>
    <Proxy GB 0.15s [HTTPS] 51.222.21.92:32768>
    <Proxy CA 0.09s [HTTP: High] 159.203.61.169:8080>
    <Proxy GB 0.19s [HTTPS] 51.222.21.95:32768>
    <Proxy GB 0.20s [HTTPS] 51.222.21.94:32768>
    <Proxy MX 0.20s [HTTPS] 169.57.1.84:8123>
    <Proxy UZ 0.30s [HTTP: High] 213.230.68.210:3128>
    <Proxy MX 0.20s [HTTPS] 169.57.1.85:80>
    <Proxy NO 0.27s [HTTP: High, HTTPS] 146.59.227.100:8888>
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems the code in your question is copy-pasted from  [Python: Correct way of using proxybroker lib with asyncio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59500799/python-correct-way-of-using-proxybroker-lib-with-asyncio)

Check it out again to see what this snippet is actually supposed to do (print proxies, instead of returning them)

As per your question, to fill result_now with the proxies generated by the broker you will need to return a value from the "reader" coroutines, which consumes async events produced through the queue by the broker.

An example with a mock replacing broker:

```py
import asyncio

async def broker_mock(proxy_queue):
    for item in [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]:
        proxy = await proxy_queue.put(item)
    await proxy_queue.put(None)

async def show(proxy_queue):
    found = []
    while True:
        proxy = await proxy_queue.get()
        if proxy is None: break
        found.append(proxy)
    return found

proxy_queue = asyncio.Queue()
tasks = asyncio.gather(broker_mock(proxy_queue), show(proxy_queue))
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
result_now = loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
print(result_now[1])
# should printout: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

I recommend reading https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html for further explanation on asyncio.